# IOS, Can i force orientation in some viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, viewcontroller

[Pic from my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2sUv.png)

im set portrait orientation in general setting
but i want to force some view controller set to landscape orientation
can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force the orientation of a view controller.

for instance...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
         return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this method in your app delegate
Example :--

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application 
   supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [SecondViewController class]])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

```
    if (secondController.isPresented)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

In More detail please refer link :--> http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code in the ViewController which you want to be in the landscape mode. Also don't forget to add landscape mode in info.plist in the Supported interface orientation.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
BOOL pushed = [self isMovingToParentViewController];

if (pushed && [[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
BOOL popped = [self isMovingFromParentViewController];

if (popped && [[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]){
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}}
```